# How to properly implement a JSONP form post submission on a Gatsby site

Tags: reactjs, jsonp, gatsby, pardot

I've got a site, created with Gatsby. There is a form on one of the pages, and it needs to post to an endpoint that doesn't support CORS, but does support JSONP.

I've written the event handler like this, using [jsonp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonp):

```
  const handleSumbit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    jsonp(
      "https://go.pardot.com/form/id/code/",
      {
        timeout: 10000,
        params: {
          firstname: "fname",
          lastname: "lname",
          email: "an@email.com",
          company: "company",
        },
      },
      (err, data) => {
        console.log({ err }, { data })
      }
    )
}
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47047487/simulate-a-jsonp-response-with-javascript-urls) post, I created 2 static files on my site called `error.json` and `success.json`. I've tried content like this in both:

```
cb({"status":"succcess"})
```

and just

```
{"status":"success"}
```

I always get an error in the console saying the request timed-out, and if I wrap the result in `jsonpCb()` I also get one saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonpCb is not defined`. I assume it's half working because it's trying to run that function, and the form data is being saved. In my React component I created a function called jsonpCb that's just this:

```
const jsonpCb = data => {
    console.log("fromJsonCb", { data })
  }
```

But I feel like that's not available to the result because of the way React packages things up.

Anyone know how I can actually get the result returned by the JSONP call?

Comment: Where does the `jsonp` function come from?

Comment: Sorry, it's the jsonp module on NPM [https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonp]

Comment: try to define cb globally as `window.jsonpCb = (data) ...`

Comment: @McB, Does this answer still work for you? I'm in basically the same predicament, but I don't see how the answer works. 

For me, I have also set up the success and error redirect URLs in Pardot. I have basically the same as you, but I can't read the response from the files. I can't even determine what file came back. I see the files in the Network tab, so they are indeed landing in my browser, but I can't access their contents. 
Any insight or repos you wouldn't mind sharing on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could get jsonp working with [this one](https://github.com/camsong/fetch-jsonp), it isn't as old as the one you are using. I would test it first with a working example (like the url I am using).

```js
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({
    loading: true,
  });
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const query = {
      callback: 'myCallback',
      url: 'https://jsonview.com/example.json',
    };
    fetchJsonp(
      'https://jsonp.afeld.me/?' +
        new URLSearchParams(query).toString()
    )
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(json) {
        console.log('query was:', query);
        setData(json);
      })
      .catch(function(ex) {
        console.log('parsing failed', ex);
      });
  }, [setData]);
  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2)}</pre>;
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch-jsonp/1.1.3/fetch-jsonp.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This is great, thanks very much. Any idea how to get the other querystring values into the result of the callback? Right now I can return an object, but in the request I can see ...myurl.com/success.js?callback=jsonpCb&otherresult=1&errors=2... Is there any way to access those other qs vars in the callback?

Comment: @McB Updated the answer.